# How to use pexpect with powershell

Tags: python, windows, powershell, pexpect

I'm trying to run commands in powershell using pexpect for windows.

Normally I start off all of my pexpect scripts by running this:

```
pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn('cmd.exe',encoding="utf-8")
```

This usually works quite well, then I can run any .expect statements I need to afterwards.

However, the moment I change my script to use powershell.exe like this:

```
pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn('powershell.exe',encoding="utf-8")
```

This ends up with powershell spawning a shell in my console window, (as in, I can interact with the powershell console, but the script cannot) and then the script will hang.

Anybody have any luck with pexpect running powershell commands?

Comment: It works for me with the combination: Windows 10, PowerShell 5.1, Python 3.5.2, pexpect 4.2.1.

Comment: I am on Powershell 5.0, I'll update and report back if that fixes my issue.

Comment: Still nada. Changing to these versions was not able to resolve this problem. Pexpect still opens a new shell visually, and python is unable to read it.

cmd.exe still works fine